# Using RedQueryBuilder directly from GWT

Tags: gwt, redquerybuilder

I would like to use redquerybuilder in my current GWT project and just inherit the redquerybuilder api in my project module xml file.  I have used the redquerybuilder jar and added the js.client to the core jar and can now inherit and compile my project using redquerybuilder as a library.  What steps do I need to take to get the querybuilder to run directly from GWT?

Answer (score 0):

It does need documenting but the basics are something like:

Configuration config = ...

Session session = new Session(config);

CommandBuilder builder = new CommandBuilder(session, sql, args);

somePanel.add(builder);

builder.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
              ..
            }
    })

The JS adapter shows a complete example:
https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/blob/master/redquerybuilder-js/src/main/java/com/redspr/redquerybuilder/js/client/RedQueryBuilder.java